# How to arrange results of a for each function into an array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

I have data that am getting from a form with multiple value of the same name. Before sending it to the url using a ajax, I want to arrange it in array before posting it. Am basically getting these values as below for all five different input fields. When I implement this using the .Push function I receive an error, "Uncaught TypeError: dArray.push is not a function"

```
            var g =  document.getElementsByName("dataA[]"); //equals 1, 11, 111

            var dArray = [];
            var eArray = [];
            var fArray = [];
            var gArray = [];
            var hArray = [];
            
    for(var i=0;i<g.length;i++){
            dArray = d[i].value;
            eArray = e[i].value;
            fArray = f[i].value;
            gArray = g[i].value;
            hArray = h[i].value;
            
            //alert(dArray); Alerts 3 times, 1, 11, then 111
            
            //I keep receiving "Uncaught TypeError: dArray.push is not a function" Error
            dArray.push(d[i].value);  //Desired [1,11,111]
            eArray.push(e[i].value);
            fArray.push(f[i].value);
            gArray.push(g[i].value);
            hArray.push(g[i].value);
            }
            
            var dArrayb = JSON.stringify(dArray);   //Desired ["1","11","111"]
            var eArrayb = JSON.stringify(eArray);
            var fArrayb = JSON.stringify(fArray);
            var gArrayb = JSON.stringify(gArray);
            var hArrayb = JSON.stringify(hArray);

            
            var dataArray = "DataD="+ dArrayb +"&DataE="+ eArrayb +"&DataF="+ fArrayb +"&DataG="+ gArrayb +"&DataH="+ hArrayb +"";
            alert(dataArray);
```

Desired Results

```
            var dataArray = DataD="["1","11","111"]"&DataE="["2","22","222"]"&DataF="["3","33","333"]"&DataG="["4","44","444"]"&DataH="["5","55","55"]"
```

Ajax send

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "SaveData.php",
    data: dataArray,
    dataType: 'json', 
    async: false,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    
    success: function (output){ 
    alert(output);
    } //success response
    
    }); //Close $.ajax
```

Comment: You're re-assigning `dArray` in the first line of your loop which makes it the type of whatever `d[i].value` is. Evidently that's not an array so you can't push anything to it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you get the error message because you are reassigning the same variables that were meant to be of type array to values inside your loop
you have to choose different variables names

```
dArray = d[i].value;
            eArr = e[i].value;
            fArr = f[i].value;
            gArr = g[i].value;
            hArr = h[i].value;


dArray.push(d[i].value);  //Desired [1,11,111]
            eArray.push(eArr);
            fArray.push(fArr);
            gArray.push(gArr);
            hArray.push(hArr);
```